# Preventing Unauthorized CMS Access

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

Recently someone tried attempting a brute force password hack of my CMS. I know this because the max attempts before a password gets locked has been reached.

I understand with this particular type of attack, strong pass phrases will help reduce the possibility of getting compromised. However, I am hoping to take this one step further.

My site is accessible on the Internet for all users to see. However, there is one page that I would like to exclude users not on my private network from seeing.

I am thinking about creating a C# method (as I am running an ASP app), that will exclude access to any addresses found not within the IP range of my private network.

How can I help reduce the possibility of a brute force password attack on my CMS login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that if you have a geometrically increasing delay between each failed password attempt, it works pretty well.

For example, start at 3 seconds and double it at every failed password attempt: 3,6,18,36,72 etc. You very, very quickly get to the point that someone is going to get very tired of waiting 10-20-30 minutes between attempts and in all likelihood will move onto an easier target.

That combined with a very difficult to guess password is pretty easy solution.

You could also add two-factor authorization using a tool such as authy pretty easily: https://www.twilio.com/authy for even more security.

Comment: Thanks, I am satisfied with this as answer for increasing the security for my login page.